# @RetraybleTopic and message consuming/processing decoupling

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using spring-kafka 2.9.6, and I've already implemented a retry system leveraging the Spring RetryableTopic feature.

Due to a limitation on the number of partitions I can create, I would like to decouple message consumption and processing.
Here's how I envision it working:

- Polls one message
- Delegates the processing to another thread pool
- Commits the offset
- Repeats this process

For retries handling I'd like to utilize the same logic and classes as RetryableTopic, possibly by manually invoking a spring-kafka method for message retry (i.e. calling a method which adds headers and sends the message to the retry topic).

Is there a way to achieve this?

And then will the DLT work "automatically" like it does in the normal RetryableTopic flow?

Answer (score 0):

You should at least be using the latest 2.9.x (currently 2.9.12). It is best to keep up-to-date within each release branch.

I have not tested it but you should be able to use a DLPR created by the `DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory` bean to send it to a retry topic. But you will need to consume the complete `ConsumerRecord<?, ?>` to have access to it (to send to the DLPR).

However, since the framework configures the same listener for all the retry containers, the same logic will apply (hand off). So, you would need to add logic to the listener that if the record is from a retry topic, process the record directly instead of handing it off to another thread. Although, handing it off should still work the same.

You also may have some subtle timing problems; it might be possible to have a record with an earlier retry timestamp "stuck behind" one with a later timestamp (but the delta will likely be small, as long as your processing times are reasonably similar).

Bear in mind also that, by prematurely committing the offset of a handed-off record, there is some risk of data loss.

Comment: To be able to use the DLPR, do i have to override RetryTopicComponentFactory#createComponentFactory#deadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory#create and inject it in a list of DLPR somewhere? Also, i'll have a DLPR per topic, how can i pick the right one to use?

Comment: You should just use the existing DLPRF (don't create another one); you can get a reference to it by overriding `RTCS.configureDeadLetterPublishingContainerFactory()`. The DLPR's destination resolver uses the topic in the record to determine the next retry topic so you, generally, wouldn't need more than one. However, to solve a problem with multiple listeners on the same topic, we had to disambiguate by adding the listener id as a parameter to the `DLPRF.create()` method, so you should create one for each listener id.